# Otool - Get file size only

Tags: xcode, terminal, otool

I'm using Otool to look into a compiled library (.a) and I want to see what the file size of each component in the binary is. I see that

otool -l [lib.a]

will show me this information but there is also a LOT of other information I do not need. Is there a way I can just see the file size and not everything else? I can't seem to find it if there is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `size` command does that, e.g.,

```
size lib.a
```

will show the size of each object stored in the `lib.a` archive.   For example:

```
$ size libasprintf.a
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
      0       0       0       0       0 lib-asprintf.o (ex libasprintf.a)
    639       8       1     648     288 autosprintf.o (ex libasprintf.a)
```

on most systems.  OS X format is a little different:

```
$ size libl.a
__TEXT  __DATA  __OBJC  others  dec     hex
86      0       0       32      118     76      libl.a(libmain.o)
75      0       0       32      107     6b      libl.a(libyywrap.o)
```

Oddly (though "everyone" implements it), I do not see `size` on the POSIX site.  OS X has a [manual page](http://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/size/) for it.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, Thomas. This will serve well for what I need. I actually found the option I could use using Otool but it was so detailed that it was annoying trying to pick out just the sizes. I do however, notice that the sizes are slightly off between Otool and this 'size' command. I don't think it will matter for what I'm trying to do but just wanted to mention it.